# length и length()

Tags: java, массивы, строки, length

Почему при получении количества элементов определяющих размер массива мы используем `array.length`, а при получении количества элементов строки используется метод `str.length()`?

Почему именно так?

Comment: отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, чтобы я мог убрать негативный голос

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В строке мы не можем четко сказать какой реальный размер строки. Для этого используется метод, в котором и подсчитывается длина строки. В массиве же при его создании мы указываем количество элементов. Это количество переменных сохраняется в публичное финальное поле `length`

Если посмотреть глубоко в метод `length()`:

```
 /**
     * Returns the length of this string.
     * The length is equal to the number of <a href="Character.html#unicode">Unicode
     * code units</a> in the string.
     *
     * @return  the length of the sequence of characters represented by this
     *          object.
     */
    public int length() {
        return value.length >> coder();
    }
```

Зайдем теперь в метод `coder()`

```
byte coder() {                                        
    return COMPACT_STRINGS ? coder : UTF16;           
}
```

Java 9 принесла нам концепцию компактных строк. `COMPACT_STRINGS` - это компактная строка , если да то возвращаем `coder`(по умолчанию 0), иначе строка не сжатая и мы возвращаем UTF16(1). 0 и 1 используется для сдвига.

Если  допустим `value.length` вернет нам 7 - а строка у нас не сжата, то будет выполнен сдвиг битов на 1. В итоге длина строки получится не 7, а 3.

Более подробно см. [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string)

Comment: Не знаю, что у вас за версия ждк, но у меня этот метод выглядит так :
    public int length() {
        return value.length;
    }

А value здесь - char array.

Comment: @aleshka-batman 10.

Comment: @aleshka-batman, это из-за компактных строк в Java 9. У Шипилёва доклад на эту тему есть отличный на ютубе.

Comment: @aleshka-batman да да сейчас в java doc как раз смотрю об этом

Comment: @aleshka-batman http://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string вот оказывается в чем дело

Comment: и всё же, в последней части ответа, сдвиг будет выполнен если строка НЕ сжата :)

Comment: @iksuy если строка сжата метод coder() вернет UTF-16 ,а это 1:)

Comment: да, это верно, я про эту часть: `Если допустим value.length вернет нам 7 - а строка у нас сжата, то будет выполнен сдвиг байтов на 1`

Comment: смотрите. value.length допустим 7, coder() - вернет 1, т.к. строка сжата. 7>>1=3

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78883/discussion-between-iksuy-and-).

Comment: @Санаев На самом деле это всего лишь дань инкапсуляции - то есть запрету прямого доступа к внутренним полям объекта. Строка в джаве неизменяема и значит ничто не мешало сделать в ней публичное финальное поле `length`, даже после введения компактных строк.

Answer (score 1):

Это всего лишь дань инкапсуляции - то есть запрету прямого доступа к внутренним полям объекта. Технически строка в Джаве неизменяема и значит ничто не мешало сделать в ней публичное финальное поле `length`, даже после введения компактных строк.

Comment: вы правы. так как ввели компактные строки, где производятся рассчеты и сделали инкапсуляцию